# How do I accelerate fisheye to hequirect conversion with cuda?

Tags: ffmpeg

This is my command

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -vf v360=input=sg:ih_fov=118.2:iv_fov=69.5:output=hequirect:w=2924:h=2924 -b:v 102400k -bufsize 5000k -c:a copy out.mp4
```

I tried

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i in.mp4 -vf v360=input=sg:ih_fov=118.2:iv_fov=69.5:output=hequirect:w=2924:h=2924 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -b:v 102400k -bufsize 5000k -c:a copy out.mp4
```

But this resulted in

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "you don't"

Presently at the time of writing (May-2022) neither the `stereo3d` or `v360` filters support GPU acceleration in `ffmpeg`. Meaning they can only be run on your CPU.

The easiest way to "accelerate" v360 transcoding/transformations with your GPU is to perform some operations on the GPU, while others on the CPU.

For v360 conversions, my pipeline normally looks roughly like

(for context this is working with ~5-7k resolution dual fisheye 180-degree 3d video with a 2:1 width/height)

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -v verbose \
    -hwaccel cuda \
    -init_hw_device cuda=c \
    -filter_hw_device c \
    -hwaccel_output_format c \
    -i "${my_file_to_process}" \
    -vf "${see_filter_chain_section}" \
    -c:v h264_nvenc \
    -c:a aac \
    -b:a 128k \
    "${output_file_path}"
```

The filter chain I use normally is

```
v360=dfisheye:fisheye:interp=line:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:d_fov=180
hw_upload_cuda
scale_cuda=w=1080:h=1080:interp_algo=bicubic:format=yuv420p
```

This normally gives me a pretty acceptable *flattening* of the video, I just do it so the video scaling to work on mobile devices. This is mostly included as an example of how to get CUDA scaling working with a CPU bound filter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, but you can get it to work by simply removing the `-hwaccel cuda` parameter from the command that you tried. It would use HW to do video encoding, however it will still be somewhat limited by v360 filter using CPU.

Example: CPU with v360 – 10 fps; without filter – 18 fps. NVENC with v360 – 34 fps; without filter – 118 fps.

Comment: Interesting. How could I have the 360 calculated with gpu, by using replacement filters that work with the gpu?